# Why does Cppcheck not detect the following format string vulnerable code?

Tags: string, security, format, cppcheck

like the following code, it is obvious fmt string vulnerability:

```
void log(char* str) {
    printf(str);
}
```

if can detect with self-defined config, how can I detect this vulnerability with CppCheck?

Comment: anyone can help me, thank u.

Comment: PVS-Studio can do this: http://www.viva64.com/en/d/0235/

Comment: GCC and Clang will also report this using `-Wformat-security` - `format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]`